# Bacmove readDeviceObjectProperty()

Tags: javascript, android, html, bacnet

can someone please tell me how to use JSInterface.readDeviceObjectProperty in Bacmove ? Their documentation is just useless.
My code:

```
function main() {

    var OBJECTS_TYPES = {
        ANALOG_INPUT: 0, 
        ANALOG_OUTPUT: 1, 
        ANALOG_VALUE: 2, 
        BINARY_INPUT: 3, 
        BINARY_OUTPUT: 4, 
        BINARY_VALUE: 5, 
        MULTI_STATE_INPUT: 13, 
        MULTI_STATE_OUTPUT: 14, 
        MULTI_STATE_VALUE: 19
    };

    var PROPERTY_IDENTIFIERS = {
        PRESENT_VALUE: 85
    };


    var DeviceID = 200;

    document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = String(JSInterface.readDeviceObjectProperty(DeviceID, OBJECTS_TYPES.BINARY_OUTPUT, 2, PROPERTY_IDENTIFIERS.PRESENT_VALUE, -1));
```

}

I am calling this function with button in HTML.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" onclick="main()" >TEST1</a>
<p id = "tt">NOPE</p>
```

Paragraph changes to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is not obvious from the documentation is that the BACnet requests are asynchronous, once the request is made, the JavaScript code receive the response of the device from the different callbacks.

In your case the innerHTML will need to be modified in the `readDeviceObjectPropertyAck` callback.

Also do not forget that prior reading you need to send a Who-Is with

```
JSInterface.whoIs();
```

and you might want to validate that your deviceId is found in:

```
JSInterface.updateDevice = function(deviceID, deviceName, segmentation, vendorID, modelName) 
{

};
```

See the modified code:

**JavaScript:**

```
var OBJECTS_TYPES = {
    ANALOG_INPUT: 0, 
    ANALOG_OUTPUT: 1, 
    ANALOG_VALUE: 2, 
    BINARY_INPUT: 3, 
    BINARY_OUTPUT: 4, 
    BINARY_VALUE: 5, 
    MULTI_STATE_INPUT: 13, 
    MULTI_STATE_OUTPUT: 14, 
    MULTI_STATE_VALUE: 19
};

var PROPERTY_IDENTIFIERS = {
    PRESENT_VALUE: 85
};

var DeviceID = 200;

function readTest1() 
{ 
    JSInterface.readDeviceObjectProperty(DeviceID, 
                                            OBJECTS_TYPES.BINARY_OUTPUT, 
                                            2, 
                                            PROPERTY_IDENTIFIERS.PRESENT_VALUE, 
                                            -1));
}

JSInterface.readDeviceObjectPropertyAck = function(deviceID, 
                                                    objectType, 
                                                    objectInstance, 
                                                    propertyIdentifier, 
                                                    arrayIndex, 
                                                    value)
{
    if ((deviceID == DeviceID) && 
        (objectType == OBJECTS_TYPES.BINARY_OUTPUT) && 
        (objectInstance == 2) && 
        (propertyIdentifier == PROPERTY_IDENTIFIERS.PRESENT_VALUE))
    {
        document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = ("" + value);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" onclick="readTest1()" >TEST1</a>
<p id = "tt">NOPE</p>
```